# How To Find Out What Was The Last Updated Field On A Lead Without History Tracking

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, history-tracking

A managed package updated a field on the Lead object but that field is not in the history tracking. Is there an easy way to find out what field was updated exactly?

The Lead has 400+ custom fields if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have 2 options if you want to track all 400 fields. Neither of which you probably want to hear:

1. Build a custom logging solution. This looks like a promising GitHub Repo that might have what you need: https://github.com/trevorrussell/SFDC-Advanced-Field-History
2. Purchase Event Monitoring from Salesforce. This is limited to 60 fields. Event Monitoring tracks all user behavior in the org. what records they view, what reports they’re running, from where, when. etc… It also includes performance metrics with every event, so you get security/audit/compliance use cases as well as data to help measure adoption and performance.

Otherwise, you'll have to use field history tracking

Comment: I was hoping to see the change in the Audit Trail but it's not there. Is it because the field is not part of the history tracking?

Comment: Event Monitoring (Field Audit Trail) has a [limit of 60 fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=field_audit_trail.htm&type=5)